# How to add folder to database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to add a folder to a database project in visual studio 2008. I've found out that database projects don't implement the full EnvDTE.Project interface. Specifically the ProjectItems property is not implemented so I can't do this:

```
dbProj.ProjectItems.AddFolder("test")
```

Does anyone know of a workaround? Is there another API available for extending visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API available.

I ended up parsing the project text file and adding the new folders that way.